# SSL certificate problem при выполнении push на github

Tags: git, github, git-push

При выполнении команды:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Пишет:

> fatal: unable to access 'https:/github.com/..../....git': SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Я понимаю, что он ругается на самоподписанный сертификат, да только ни в ~/.ssh ни на гитхабе сртификатов у меня нет.

Git свежий. Кто что думает? Как исправить?

Comment: Там точно github.com? У них далеко не самоподписанные сертификаты. Если да - у вас проблема с безопасностью системы - провретесь на вирусы и т.п. Что-то перехватывает ваш SSL-трафик.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь достучаться по https, почему в вопросе упомянут ssh?

Comment: Стоит лицензионный KIS - параноик ещё тот он рубит даже то что не нужно иногда .... думаю тут что-то другое ...

Comment: Просто подумал, что вопрос в сертификатах ssh ... не прав? ... а что тогда?

Comment: @Алексей, ну KIS не спасет от перехвата трафика, особенно если он выполняется не на вашей системе, а у вас просто кто-то заранее добавил игнорирование ошибок в браузере и т.п.

Comment: Есть предположение, что это как раз из-за KIS - он прописывает свой сертификат к каждому сайту, ну и что делать? не вырубать же касперыча ...

Comment: @Алексей, попробуйте снять эту галочку - http://support.kaspersky.ru/6271 , Добровольно разрешать какой-то программе(даже KIS) перехватывать ваш SSL-трафик - это мягко говоря неправильно.

Comment: Это не может быть опечаткой в remotes? У вас тут один слеш после `https`: `fatal: unable to access 'https:/github.com/......`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

KIS 2015 в Firefox автоматически по умолчанию устанавливает свой сертификат и делает автоматическую проверку всех защищённых соединений. Для этого он подменяет сертификаты сайтов на свой сертификат в браузере!

Чтобы убрать подмену сертификатов:

В настройках KIS 2015: Настройка/Дополнительно/Сеть(параметры сети) - снять галочку с "Проверять защищённые соединения" и перезагрузить комп.

Comment: Всё просто: в настройках KIS 2015:  Настройка/Дополнительно/Сеть(параметры сети) - снять галочку с "Проверять защищённые соединения" и перезагрузить комп. И всё - сертификат касперыча уберётся.

Comment: отлично, добавил решение в ваш ответ. Если не трудно, отметьте галочкой, чтобы обозначить действующее решение.

Comment: Можно просто приостановить защиту KIS на несколько минут (контекстное меню по иконке в трее -> приостановить защиту) и в этот момент выполнить команду

Answer (score 2):

Для игнорирования HTTPS-сертификатов в Git достаточно в файле конфигурации пользователя/системы/репозитория выставить параметр [http.sslVerify](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_variables) в значение false:

```
[http]
sslVerify false
```

Однако в случае с github-ом это не правильно - нужно искать причину того, почему они самоподписанные.

Comment: Да, про sslVerify false знаю ... но это действительно не вариант ... а решение уже пол дня найти не могу ...

Comment: В `git-config(1)` нынче предлагают более развесистый пример с отключением для конкретного сайта (у меня это был интранетный с самоподписанным сертификатом) с вот таким заголовком секции: `[http "https://weak.example.com"]`

Answer (score 1):

если вы зарегистрированы на `github`-е и публичная часть вашего ключа добавлена в учётную запись, то можно соединяться с `github`-ом по протоколу *ssh*.

ссылку на репозиторий можно получить на странице репозитория (см. справа: «You can clone with HTTPS, SSH, or Subversion») либо, уже имея http-ссылку, преобразовать её в ssh-ссылку, заменив `https://` на `git@` и первый слэш после адреса сайта — на двоеточие. пример:

```
https://github.com/owncloud/android.git
    git@github.com:owncloud/android.git
```

если репозиторий уже склонирован, и требуется лишь подправить ссылку, то это можно сделать примерно такой командой:

```
$ git remote set-url origin <ссылка>
```

посмотреть свои публичные ключи, закреплённые за учётной записью на *github*-е можно на соответствующей [странице настроек](https://github.com/settings/ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно скачать CA с сайта [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html):

```
curl -k https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -o /path/to/cacert.pem
```

А затем экспортировать путь к сертификату в переменные окружения:

```
export GIT_SSL_CAINFO=/path/to/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Только что была аналогичная проблема, два одинаковых компьютера. На одном работает, на другом нет. Сверил версии KIS, GIT, Tortoise Git. Обновил все до самых последних (18.0.0.405h, 2.17.0, 2.6.0.0) - заработало.